# How i can create an array of strings and make it available to all the method inside our C# console application

Tags: c#

I have the following console application:-

```
namespace MSE
{
    class Program
    {
        private static async Task<ScanInfo> gettingCustomerInfo(string name, long Id)
        {
            // code goes here..
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            //code goes here..
            var tasks = companies.Select(c => Task.Run(() => gettingCustomerInfo(c.properties.name.value, c.companyId)));
            //code goes here...
        }
    }
}
```

now i want to data from a text file and populate a list of string with these data, then to make this list available to all the console application methods.. so not sure how i can define such an array,, here is the code to build the array:-

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\file.txt");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    list.Add(line);
}
```

so how i can create such as list and make it available inside all the methods?

Comment: Add a static version of this variable to teh programm class, as a "brother" of the main function and all other functions. Normally static should be avodied like the plague, but in this case it should not mater.

Comment: Declare a `private static List<string>` variable that belongs to `class` Program and populate it immediately in `Main`

Comment: Declare your list as a global variable ( `List<string> list;`), and then do the setup for it (`new List, read all lines, and your foreach`) in your main method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare `list` globally and then you can use it throughout the class.

```
namespace MSE
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> list;

        private static async Task<ScanInfo> gettingCustomerInfo(string name, long Id)
        {
            // code goes here..
        }

        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            list = new List<string>();
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\file.txt");
            foreach (var line in lines)
            {
                list.Add(line);
            }
            var tasks = companies.Select(c => Task.Run(() => 
            gettingCustomerInfo(c.properties.name.value, c.companyId)));
            //code goes here...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all functions of the class "Program" need to access it, it must be part of the class.

As all those functions are also static, the variable itself must be too.

Normally static variable are something to be avoided. They are globals and globals are a terrible idea. In this case (console application), it should not mater however. Just replace your current intitialsiation and declaration with this one:

```
namespace MSE
{
    class Program
    {
        static List<string> list = new List<string>();

        private static async Task<ScanInfo> gettingCustomerInfo(string name, long Id)
        {
         // code goes here..
        }
```

Note that if you keep both codes, the local copy in the function will hide the classwide one while it is in scope.

Edit: I just noticed that you seem to be trying to learn multitasking. I would not advise to learn mutltiasking in a Console Application. It just adds a dozen *additional* issue to something that is already dang complicated. Always try to learn mutltiasking using a GUI application, even basic WindowsForms is better then console.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but can i know why i should avoid multitasking inside console application? i am not learning multitasking, i am already using this in many live console apps and i never face any issue of doing multi-threading in console app.. in my case i need to call external api and instead of doing single call , i am sending 20 requests to the external api at the same time and store the result inside my system, this has improved the performance for my app..

Comment: @testtest The big issues is keeping the programm alive, while also responding to tasks. In console you have to write that yourself. This is trivialy easy to mess up. But GUI's alrady do that. Keeping the programm alive and reacting to changes is what the EventQueue does.